# How to select number that follow any symbol except whitespace

Tags: regex

How can I select number that follows any symbol except space

```
word23 
#3 
*9
@user82
```

But not select this

```
 123
```

Comment: Any whitespace or an actual **space** ?

Comment: @hwnd I make a mistake and edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An expression with *negative look-behind* `(?<!a)b` matches "`b` not preceeded by `a`", so in your case it would be

```
(?<![\s\d])\d+
```

`\d+` means "a sequence of one or more decimal digits". `[\s\d]` means "a space character or a digit", which includes spaces, tabs, etc.

[Demo.](https://regex101.com/r/zC8nZ3/1)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify what language/engine you are using, so instead of using a lookaround assertion I used a group construct to simulate the behavior of the actual lookaround.

```
(?:^|[^\s\d])(\d+)
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/uS2pX6/2)

Comment: Thank you, but this RE selects one symbol before a number.
I need only a number and RE in second answer does exactly what I need.

Comment: Yes, the preceding symbol is not an issue because your match result is stored in capturing group `#1`

Comment: How I can get this stored result?

Comment: I use this RE in Sublime Text Find&Replace func

Comment: Since you didn't previous specify that, yes to only select the number in Sublime you would need to either replace the string and reference the group or use a lookaround, i.e. `(^|[^\s\d])\K\d+`